# How can I send multiple items to FBA Amazon createFulfillmentOrder

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I want to Requests Amazon ship items from the seller's inventory to a destination address. I am doing it using Amazon createFulfillmentOrder. Below is my code, for one item it is working fine, But I am not sure how can I use it when we have multiple items in one order. Please help.

```
 $item = new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderItem();
 //Set item parameters
 $item-> setSellerSKU("XX-XXX-XX-XX");
 $item-> setSellerFulfillmentOrderItemId("XX");                 
 $item-> setQuantity("XX");

 $obOrderItemList =new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderItemList();
 $obOrderItemList->setmember($item);

 $request->setItems($obOrderItemList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Multiple Items**

```
$obOrderItemList =new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderItemList();
foreach($itemsArray as $key=>$val) {    
    $item = new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderItem();
    //Set item parameters
    $item-> setSellerSKU($val['SKU']); //sku            
    $item-> setSellerFulfillmentOrderItemId("mws-".$val['id']); //unique id             
    $item-> setQuantity($val['item_quantity']); //item quantity                     
    $obOrderItemList->withmember($item);
}                   
$request->setItems($obOrderItemList);
```

**Single Item**

```
$item = new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderItem();
//Set item parameters
$item-> setSellerSKU($itemSKU);
$item-> setSellerFulfillmentOrderItemId($uniqueItemId);                 
$item-> setQuantity($item_quantity);
$obOrderItemList =new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderItemList();                 
$obOrderItemList->setmember($item);
$request->setItems($obOrderItemList);
```

Comment: Good job! The Foreach works well for multiple or single!

Comment: Thank you very much. I would have never figured this our from the docs.